# How can I output this text with PHP?

Tags: php, html

I created a little script to generate a list of years from 1905 to 2012 for use with an HTML form. This basically prevented me from handwriting it.

How would I go about outputting something that looks like this in the browser:

```
<option value="2012">2012</option>
<option value="2011">2011</option>
<option value="2010">2010</option>
etc...
```

My PHP Script

```
<?php

for ($i=2012;$i>=1905;$i--) {
echo "<option value='$i'>" . $i . "</option>";
}

?>
```

Comment: what about using a [datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/)?

Comment: It isn't clear at all what you mean by "outputting something like this in the browser"

Comment: Your code *will* output that in the browser.  I don't understand.

Comment: Do you mean you want to be able to view/copy the generated code? You can do that by setting a plain text header (`header("Content-Type: text/plain");`) or by running the output through [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).

Comment: I hate year pickers as a dropdown. It takes far longer to hunt through the list to find the right year than it does to type in the year you want.

Comment: Figured it out: <?php

for ($i=2012;$i>=1905;$i--) {
 $output =  "<option value='$i'>" . $i . "</option>";
 echo "<br />";
 echo htmlspecialchars($output);
}

?>

Answer (score 1):

You are very close, only the quotes differ in the output and the line-break is missing:

```
for ($i=2012; $i >= 1905; $i--) {
    echo "<option value=\"$i\">$i</option>\n";
}
```

Or probably better to read/manage

```
for ($i=2012; $i >= 1905; $i--) {
    printf("<option value=\"%1\$d\">%1\$d</option>\n", $i);
}
```

[Demo](http://codepad.org/0NW8oEIU), output:

```
<option value="2012">2012</option>
<option value="2011">2011</option>
<option value="2010">2010</option>
<option value="2009">2009</option>
<option value="2008">2008</option>
<option value="2007">2007</option>
<option value="2006">2006</option>
<option value="2005">2005</option>
<option value="2004">2004</option>
<option value="2003">2003</option>
<option value="2002">2002</option>
<option value="2001">2001</option>
<option value="2000">2000</option>
<option value="1999">1999</option>
<option value="1998">1998</option>
<option value="1997">1997</option>
<option value="1996">1996</option>
<option value="1995">1995</option>
<option value="1994">1994</option>
<option value="1993">1993</option>
<option value="1992">1992</option>
<option value="1991">1991</option>
<option value="1990">1990</option>
<option value="1989">1989</option>
<option value="1988">1988</option>
<option value="1987">1987</option>
<option value="1986">1986</option>
<option value="1985">1985</option>
<option value="1984">1984</option>
<option value="1983">1983</option>
<option value="1982">1982</option>
<option value="1981">1981</option>
<option value="1980">1980</option>
<option value="1979">1979</option>
<option value="1978">1978</option>
<option value="1977">1977</option>
<option value="1976">1976</option>
<option value="1975">1975</option>
<option value="1974">1974</option>
<option value="1973">1973</option>
<option value="1972">1972</option>
<option value="1971">1971</option>
<option value="1970">1970</option>
<option value="1969">1969</option>
<option value="1968">1968</option>
<option value="1967">1967</option>
<option value="1966">1966</option>
<option value="1965">1965</option>
<option value="1964">1964</option>
<option value="1963">1963</option>
<option value="1962">1962</option>
<option value="1961">1961</option>
<option value="1960">1960</option>
<option value="1959">1959</option>
<option value="1958">1958</option>
<option value="1957">1957</option>
<option value="1956">1956</option>
<option value="1955">1955</option>
<option value="1954">1954</option>
<option value="1953">1953</option>
<option value="1952">1952</option>
<option value="1951">1951</option>
<option value="1950">1950</option>
<option value="1949">1949</option>
<option value="1948">1948</option>
<option value="1947">1947</option>
<option value="1946">1946</option>
<option value="1945">1945</option>
<option value="1944">1944</option>
<option value="1943">1943</option>
<option value="1942">1942</option>
<option value="1941">1941</option>
<option value="1940">1940</option>
<option value="1939">1939</option>
<option value="1938">1938</option>
<option value="1937">1937</option>
<option value="1936">1936</option>
<option value="1935">1935</option>
<option value="1934">1934</option>
<option value="1933">1933</option>
<option value="1932">1932</option>
<option value="1931">1931</option>
<option value="1930">1930</option>
<option value="1929">1929</option>
<option value="1928">1928</option>
<option value="1927">1927</option>
<option value="1926">1926</option>
<option value="1925">1925</option>
<option value="1924">1924</option>
<option value="1923">1923</option>
<option value="1922">1922</option>
<option value="1921">1921</option>
<option value="1920">1920</option>
<option value="1919">1919</option>
<option value="1918">1918</option>
<option value="1917">1917</option>
<option value="1916">1916</option>
<option value="1915">1915</option>
<option value="1914">1914</option>
<option value="1913">1913</option>
<option value="1912">1912</option>
<option value="1911">1911</option>
<option value="1910">1910</option>
<option value="1909">1909</option>
<option value="1908">1908</option>
<option value="1907">1907</option>
<option value="1906">1906</option>
<option value="1905">1905</option>
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you! I don't have enough reputation points to accept this answer or vote it up. This is the correct answer I was looking for!

Comment: You will be able to accept the answer later on (you don't need any rep to accept an answer of one of your questions), there only is some time-period you need to let pass until you can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i=2012;$i>=1905;$i--) {
echo "<option value='$i'>" . $i . "</option>";
}
```

you forgot to echo $i in the value properly so it wont work

use this instead, notice the value field. and as other comments surgested u can use a  datpicker

```
for ($i=2012;$i>=1905;$i--) {
echo "<option value='".$i."'>" . $i . "</option>";
}
```

Comment: PHP has variable substitution in double quoted strings, see http://php.net/string#language.types.string.parsing.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select>
    <?php for ($i=2012;$i>=1905;$i--) { ?>

    <option value=<?=$i?>> <?=$i?> </option>

    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Just a tip. Avoid printing html with echo.